# Is this the reason why IEquatable<T> was introduced?

Tags: c#

Is main reason why `IEquatable<T>` interface was introduced because it allows you to do the same as the `System.Object.Equals` method but without having to perform casts?

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it type safe, I would think. `Equals()` takes an object as parameter and hence you will not see an error if you pass in an object of wrong type until you run it.

Answer (score 3):

One reason is so that you can require a class be equatable with a desired type, without necessarily being that type. E.g.

```
public void MyClass<T> where T : IEquatable<Foo>
{
    private static readonly Foo SpecialFoo = Foo.SpecialFoo;

    public void MyMethodThatProcessesTs(T theT)
    {
        if (theT.Equals(SpecialFoo))
        {
            // process theT.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what @Bala R says, it also avoids boxing when doing custom equality checking between structs.